# Using Bitmap for android consuming lot of memory

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap, bitmapimage

In my android app,I am displaying various images from gallery whose paths are stored in a database and on runtime it uses bitmap to display image from these paths and due to this it is consuming lot of memory.It is crashing in many mobiles although I am reducing the quality of image. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Post the relevant code snippets. And how much exactly is your *lot of memory*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd strongly suggest looking into image libraries such as Picasso and Glide. Displaying bitmaps natively in Android requires a fair amount of coding to ensure issues like Outofmemory error do not occur.